# Open webpage with pre-determined cookie set

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, session-state, session-cookies

I have a .NET application that internally communicates with a router interface that is (obviously) not within my control to change. Amongst things, it does a login and tracks the appropriate cookies for it. While most functionality of this interface sucks, some things are actually done right and not worth duplicating, and as such I wish to put a direct link inside my application to open the appropriate page. Trick is: I want to avoid logging the user in a second time, and stick my cookies into the browser, since logging in alone can take 3-5 seconds, nevermind opening the proper page with the proper data.

Preferably this solution is cross-platform, but I am fine with an IE-only solution. Oh, and ideally the cookie gets deleted upon closing the new window, given the fact that my application will keep the server-side timeout mechanism from kicking in, but if that isn't possible I can live with it. :)

Comment: Is the destination URL an IP address, a fully qualified domain name (`http://example.com`) or just a short server name without a domain (`http://example`)?

Comment: It is an ip address in the 192.168.x.x class of addresses, although it is also accessible under a http://example style server name. (At present the device does not support ipv6 yet, if that is relevant in any way.)

Answer (score 0):

You could in your .NET application create a temporary HTML file that contains JavaScript to set the cookie and redirect to the router via the`http://example` name.  When you are writing the HTML file, you would add in the cookie value that you had already created.

If the browser does not allow the cookie without the domain to work, you would need to host a webpage on a webserver in the same domain as the router, and on that webserver have an html page that takes the cookie as a URL query string parameter and set the cookie via javascript using the value from the query string.

Comment: First of all, I am not too deeply aware of the possibilities and limitations of cookies, but last I heard cookies were bound to 'servers' for security reasons, and as such being able to set a cookie for another server would be a security issue, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Stigma I have updated my answer in the case that the cookie with no domain does not work in your browser.